# Exception from Dns.GetHostAddress even though it returns a good result if output to a messagebox

Tags: c#, exception, dns, ping

I'm getting an IP from a hostname like this:

```
IPAddress[] serverIp = Dns.GetHostAddresses(serverFqdn);
string firstResult = serverIp[0].ToString();
```

If I then call up firstResult in a messageBox like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(firstResult);
```

The messagebox pops up with the correct IP address.

However, if instead of a messagebox I proceed to use that IP address for a ping test like this:

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(firstResult);
```

I get a 'SocketException' with error code 11001 no such host is known in relation to the code line with the DNS query.

How can this happen when the dns query is clearly successful in the first scenario?

EDIT:
If I insert the messagebox in between the DNS query and the ping, it pops up with the IP address as it should. When I dismiss the messagebox, the code proceeds to the ping and then there is an exception on the dns query line of code, which executed BEFORE the messagebox.

This is the part I don't understand. How can a method that was clearly executed synchronously and successfully generate an exception after the next line of code has also run successfully?

Comment: Instead of `pingSender.Send(firstResult)`, can you try `pingSender.Send(serverIp[0])` and see if you have the same exception ?

Comment: yes i already tried that. issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

this is because ping.send() expects an IPAdress object as a paramter, so you need to use the static IPAdress.parse() method to obtain an IPAdress object first.
Then, use the returned object as a parameter for your Ping.send() call.

Comment: The method Send can accept different types of parameters according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem although still unsure why the IDE was showing the exception in the wrong place.

One of the calls to this ping test method was sending in an IP instead of a server name. The ping test method was appending a domain name then the ping test was trying to use (for example)

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("192.168.1.1.domain.com");
```

Comment: In this case, it should have worked with this line of code : `pingSender.Send(serverIp[0])`